# “Couldn't find [model] without an ID” Rails 3.2.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, controller, associations, form-for

For some reason, I keep getting this error.

> Couldn't find Album without an ID

But that doesn't make sense because in my debug.params it says:

> > {"utf8"=>"✓",
> >
> > "authenticity_token"=>"os9DVVZS6//bs3Ne2Xfrh4VnKXNtDXkZaE4s/3iQagE=",
> >
> > "video"=>{"url"=>"www.youtube.com/watch?v=yIRuri1AB0I",
> >
> > "album_id"=>"1"},
> >
> > "commit"=>"Next"}

Here is the controller:

> class VideosController < ApplicationController
>
> include AlbumsHelper
>
> before_filter :signed_in_user, only: [:create, :destroy] #add update later
>
> before_filter :correct_user, only: :destroy

```
def show
    @video = Video.find(params[:id])
end

def new
    if signed_in?
        @album = Album.find(params[:album_id])
    @video = @album.build_video
end
end

def create 
    @album = Album.find(params[:album_id])
    @video = @album.build_video(params[:video])
    if @video.save 
        flash[:success] = "Success!"
        redirect_to new_small_reward_path(:album_id => @album)
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end
```

> end

I even added a hidden field to the form, which I didn't think I should have to do, but decided to try:

> 

The URL says /videos/new?album_id=1 before you click submit.

This problem completely goes away if I write the controller with this:

> def new
>
> @@album = Album.find(params[:album_id])
>
> end

and then continue to use the class variable throughout the entire thing. But someone told me that using a class variable is discouraged. How do I do this correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> @album = Album.find(params[:video][:album_id])

Comment: and u have to use hidden field (@video = @album.build_video  => attribute for hidden field)

Comment: Hidden field? What attribute is in the hidden field?